# What's the c++ inline class?

Tags: c++, class, inline, clang

I accidentally found that the Clang compiler allows :

```
inline class AAA
{
};
```

in C++.
What's this?

---

PS. I reported this to Clang mailing list `cfe-dev@cs.uiuc.edu`, and now waiting for reply. I'll update this question by I'm informed.

Comment: inline function makes sense....but inline class??

Comment: "What's this?" - Something that doesn't exist in standard C++. The `inline` specifier is for functions, not classes. You may have stumbled upon a bug in the Clang C++ compiler.

Comment: Added `clang` tag, I could not find anything on the bug tracker, it might be worth opening one (you could always post a mail to cfe-dev [at] cs.uiuc.edu beforehand if you're unsure). If this is on the 2.9 line, they'll probably want to fix it soon.

Comment: This may be something that tells the compiler not to generate object-oriented code for the class you defined. Maybe it expands the class declaration and memory management into the user code to make speed faster.

Comment: Thanks guys. I have reported this to `cfe-dev@cs.uiuc.edu`. And I'm waiting for reply.

Comment: They replied it's a bug. However it had been fixed already.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got an answer from Clang mailing list. It was a bug: 
http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=3941

However it looks already been fixed in recent build.
Thanks anyway :)

Here's the conversation:
http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2011-March/014207.html

Answer (score 48):

It's allowed in case you wish to declare a function that returns an object of that class directly after the class' declaration, for example :

```
#include <iostream>

inline class AAA 
{
public:
    AAA()
    {
        // Nothing
    }

    AAA(const AAA& _Param)
    {
        std::cout << "Calling Copy Constructor of AAA\n";
    }
}A()
 {
     AAA a;
     return a;
 };

int main()
{
    A();
    return 0;
}
```

Also you should notice the compiler errors (or warnings) that appear in other illegal cases, such as declaring a variable instead of `A()`, also notice that the compiler states that it ignores the `inline` keyword if you didn't declare any function.

Hope that's helpful.

**Edit : For The comment of Eonil**

If you are talking about your code above in the question, then it's the same case as I see, the compiler will give you a warning : `'inline ' : ignored on left of 'AAA' when no variable is declared`

However, if you use the code in my answer but replace `A()` with a variable, `B` for example, it will generate a compiler error : `'B' : 'inline' not permitted on data declarations`

So we find that the compiler made no mistake with accepting such declarations, how about trying to write `inline double;` on its own? It will generate a warning : `'inline ' : ignored on left of 'double' when no variable is declared`

Now how about this declaration :

```
double inline d()
{
}
```

It gives no warnings or errors, it's exactly the same as :

```
inline double d()
{
}
```

since ***the precedence of `inline` is not important at all.***

The first code (in the whole answer) is similar to writing :

```
class AAA
{
    // Code
};

inline class AAA A()
{
    // Code
}
```

which is legal.

And, in other way, it can be written as :

```
class AAA
{
    // Code
};

class AAA inline A()
{
    // Code
}
```

You would be relieved if you see the first code (in the whole answer) written like :

```
#include <iostream>

class AAA 
{
    // Code
} inline A()
 {
    // Code
 };
```

But they are the same, since there is no importance for the precedence of `inline`.

Hope it's clear and convincing.

Comment: My eyes!! +1 though for a nice and cryptic example when this works. :)

Comment: Could you elaborate WTF, is happening here? Why would I ever declare a function like that, and is that function a method of the class?

Comment: @polemon: This function is not a method of that class, it's a function on its own, you could declare funciton or variable immediately after the closing brace and before the semicolon `;` and it (the function) will return an object of that class (and the variable will be an object of that class). And for reason, I don't actually have any reason for functions, there may be some reasons for variables, yet I don't have any of them in mind right now.

Comment: @Mr.TAMER's particular construct _might_ be legal (and it's _definitely_ crazy), but if there's no function, I think the compiler ought to _reject_ it, not warn about it. (And the clang version with Xcode4 does neither.) This still smells like a bug to me. Does anyone have chapter&verse from the standard on this?

Comment: Great description. But unfortunately, I tried to compile exactly same code which I instanced. And Clang did compile it without any error. So obviously it's not this case.

Comment: @TamerShlash Is this allowed in c++11? I get some linker errors saying undefined reference.

Comment: Might be helpful to clarify that "It's allowed in case you wish to declare a **inline** function..."

Answer (score 16):

clang shouldn't allow this, `inline` can only be used in the declaration of functions, from ISO/IEC 14882:2003 7.1.2 [dcl.fct.spec] / 1 :

> *Function-specifiers* can be used only in function declarations.

`inline` is one of three *function-specifiers*, `virtual` and `explicit` being the others.

As @MatthieuM notes, in the next version of C++ (C++0x), the `inline` keyword will also be allowed in namespace definitions (with different semantics to `inline` as a *function-specifier*).

Comment: In the context of C++0x, it can be used with namespaces too.

Comment: @Matthieu: Could you expand on that?